# swift protocol conformance when same property name is optional

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

When a protocol declares a property as *optional* and a concrete type declares it as *non-optional*, how can I make the concrete type conform to the protocol?

Here's the problem:

```swift
protocol Track {
    var trackNumber: Int? { get } // not all tracks have a track number
}

struct SpotifyTrack {
    let trackNumber: Int // all SpotifyTrack are guaranteed to have a track number
}

extension SpotifyTrack: Track {
    var trackNumber: Int? {
        return self.trackNumber // WARNING: All paths through this function will call itself
    }
}
```

I don't want to make `trackNumber` optional in `SpotifyTrack` because I know the value will always be there for SpotifyTracks. Are there are any solutions more elegant than just renaming the properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no elegant solution to your problem other than renaming the conflicting property on the conforming type.

Swift doesn't allow 2 properties of the same name to exist on a type even if their types are different. On the other hand, `Int?` and `Int` are completely different types, so you cannot have `trackNumber: Int` fulfil the protocol requirement of `trackNumber: Int?`.

The only solution (other than changing the type in either the `protocol` or the `struct`) is to rename the non-Optional property in `SpotifyTrack` and make an optional computed property of the same name returning the non-optional one.

```
protocol Track {
    var trackNumber: Int? { get }
}
struct SpotifyTrack {
    private let _trackNumber: Int
}
extension SpotifyTrack: Track {
    var trackNumber: Int? { _trackNumber }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a second property that acts as backing for the first:

```
protocol Track {
    var trackNumber: Int? { get }
}
struct SpotifyTrack {
    var realTrackNumber: Int
}
extension SpotifyTrack: Track {
    var trackNumber: Int? { self.realTrackNumber }
}
```

However, I have a feeling that that is what you mean by "renaming": you would prefer not to do that. Nevertheless, the "instructions" of a protocol are firm: you cannot adopt Track without declaring a `trackNumber` that is explicitly typed as `Int?`.

Objective-C has `@optional` protocol members, meaning you could have Track declare `trackNumber` Int but `@optional`, and then you could adopt Track without having a `trackNumber` *at all*. But if you wanted to take advantage of that, this could not be a struct.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is indeed what I was referring to by "renaming" the property; as it makes for an awkward name (a spotify track's track number isn't actually "real")

Comment: Well, the convention really is just as David Pasztor suggested, using an underscore. I just used "Real" to make it easy to see what I was doing. :) Nonetheless he is saying exactly the same thing I am.

Comment: The point of my answer, however, is that the prescription of a protocol is absolutely dispositive. It tells you what you must say in order to adopt the protocol. So either you would need a different protocol (as another answer suggests) or you must live with the "renaming". Or just do nothing! An Optional is not a heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be that you have a base track protocol and then have a second protocol which extend the base protocol. For example

```
protocol BaseTrackProtocol {
    var title:String
    var artist:String
}

protocol SpotifyTrackProtocol : BaseTrackProtocol {
    var trackNumber:Int
}

struct SoptifyTrack: SpotifyTrackProtocol {
    var title:String
    var artist:String
    var trackNumber:Int
}
```

other type of tracks could then follow different extensions of the base track protocol

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It is only allowed in one condition one of the 2 properties must be static:

```swift
class MyClass {
    static let id = "MyClass"

    let id = "MyClass"
}

struct MyStruct {
    static let id = "MyClass"
    
    let id = "MyClass"
}
```